# What is the first ever ERC20 token creation transaction?

Tags: erc-20

Do you know the first ERC20 issuance transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following token is the first ERC-20 compliant token. If you don't agree with that. Can you correct me?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9e7b5966b33b4393f250bfcf45eed7751d44981b6d8dec9422a0bd2a2c698306

https://etherscan.io/tokens?q=0x89d64bc7e46bdc49a89652ae9bb167418cbad62e

```
On-chain Token Attributes detected: 
 totalSupply = 1000000000
 name = Ether Token Proxy
 symbol = ETH
 decimals = 18
```

Answer (score 1):

I found token tx from block 462680  [`Transaction`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x806172DA2073B5C3D961A8C613B7E469766AD19C6220DD0ED35676FE576C625A)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I found this transaction with `Transfer` event. https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe2b6c91ffa7e53114df437c2b7ed261672cbfff805aba3dc15bd4d825fdcb6d5

Block height 447,767.

The contract, however, doesn't have the source and probably doesn't implement all ERC20 methods.